# Conditional attribute action in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two radio fields in my code...

```
<div class="article-votes-controls" role="radiogroup">
<a role="radio" rel="nofollow" class="button article-vote article-vote-up" title="Sim" aria-selected="false" href="#"></a>
<a role="radio" rel="nofollow" class="button article-vote article-vote-down " title="Não" aria-selected="true" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

I need to show another div (.example) when the article-vote-down radio button is selected and the attribute "aria-selected" change to "true", if false hide.

Tried something like...

```
if ( $('.article-vote-down').attr('aria-selected') == 'true' ) {
    $('.example').show();
} else {
    $('.example').hide();
}
```

But this works only when i load the page and the atributte is already there... I need to make the code listen the change of attribute without reloading the entire page.

Improvised like this... have another better way?

```
$(".article-vote-down").click(function() {
    if ( $('.article-vote-down').attr('aria-selected') == 'false' ) {
    $('.example').show();
} else if ( $('.article-vote-down').attr('aria-selected') == 'true' ) {
    $('.example').hide();
}
});
  $(".article-vote-up").click(function() {
    $('.example').hide();
});
```

Comment: Voting to close as you are asking someone to write the code for you, this is evident because you did not provide your attempted jQuery code in your question

Comment: Actually i tried a lot... do not jump to conclusions whitout asking first ;)

Comment: I posted the code i tried... but didn't work... just the else action is working

Comment: This $('.article-vote-down') maybe an array of jQuery elements, if if there is only one HTML element. jQuery is old school so I do not remember off the top of my head. You question is still poorly structured, you do not example any error messages or output of your jQuery attempt code.

Comment: Thanks Brian... actually i discovered that the code works... but just when the attribute it's already there... If i load the page and the value is true... the .example appears... if i load and the value is false hide. How can we make this code listen the html to any changes without reloading the page?

Comment: Glad you figured it out, the rewards of programming are small yet mighty :)

Comment: You know how to make work in JQuery or Javascript? Sorry i do not speak english very well and im trying to resume my problem